# Error when printing how many levels are visible in tree in PHP

Tags: php, class, tree

I am receiving the error "Using $this when not in object context". I think I might be using the class node incorrectly. I cannot figure out where I am going wrong at this point.

I am trying to get the answer 4 in the case of a tree like the below. This is because there are 4 visible layers.

```
$root = new TreeNode(8);
$root->left = new TreeNode(3);
$root->right = new TreeNode(10);
$root->left->left = new TreeNode(1);
$root->left->right = new TreeNode(6);
$root->left->right->left = new TreeNode(4);
$root->left->right->right = new TreeNode(7);
$root->right->right = new TreeNode(14);
$root->right->right->left = new TreeNode(13);


 class TreeNode{
  public $val;
  public $left;
  public $right;
  public function __construct($val=0) {
    $this->val = $val;
    $this->left = NULL;
    $this->right = NULL;
  }
}


function findLeft($root){
   $queue = $root;
   
  while(!empty($queue)){
     $size = sizeof($queue);
     $i = 0;
    $answer = 0;
       while($i<$size){
          
         $i= $i+1;
         //if first node print
         if ($i == 1){
           $answer += 1;
         }
         if($this->left){
           array_push($queue, $this->left);
         }
         
         if($this->right){
           array_push($queue, $this->right);
         }
         array_unshift($queue); //shift first  item
         }
       } return $queue;
   }
  
//calling function
function visibleNodes($root) {
  // Write your code here
  if(empty($root)){
    return 0;
  } else {
   
  $answer = findLeft($root);
  }
     return $answer;
}
```

Comment: Your class syntax is wrong. Your methods must be within the scope of the class, that is.

Comment: It is unclear what you're doing. Setting `$queue` to `$root` makes it an instance of `TreeNode`, and in function `findLeft` your are trying to push into it, which you can not. because it is not an array. Also, your are returning `$queue` from  `findLeft` which seems wrong and your want to return `$answer` probably. Read more on tree traversal algorithms and also learn more php syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I'll keep researching